# Nginx not excuting php

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I am using Nginx for a couple of websites.  First time user of it and not that happy (Apache will not work in my case).  I am trying to use PHP for a new project that requires it. I have PHP 7.3 FPM. To test, phpinfo(); does work however when adding this project (openCAD), index.php seems to be blank.

I tried putting on MyBB to see if that executes and it simply does not, just a blank page.

Here is my nginx config

```
server {

        root /var/www/mywebsite.com/;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;



         location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}



server {
    if ($host = www.appeal.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com/appeal;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = appeal.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com/appeal;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.appeal.mywebsite.com appeal.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}

server {


    if ($host = www.cad.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com/cad;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = cad.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://mywebsite.com/cad;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.cad.mywebsite.com cad.mywebsite.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Here is the error log for trying to access MyBB

```
2019/08/20 15:48:11 [error] 23516#23516: *71 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/mywebsite.com/php/inc/init.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/mywebsite.com/php/global.php on line 20PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/www/mywebsite.com/php/inc/init.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/mywebsite.com/php/global.php on line 20" while reading response header from upstream, client: 70.44.50.53, server: mywebsite.com, request: "GET /php/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock:", host: "mywebsite.com"
```

Comment: If phpinfo() executes, the nginx and PHP installation is OK. From the error message it's quite likely you have issues with how paths are resolved or permission issues. Have you verified `/var/www/mywebsite.com/php/inc/init.php` exists? Does it have file permissions set correctly?

Comment: Well, did you look at `/var/www/mywebsite.com/php/global.php` on line 20? Does that file exist?

Comment: Well here is what's happening.  I have it on a subdirector of /mywebsite.com as it should only be accessed by sub directory.  When I go to that directory, it wants me to download an unknown file but when I specify index.php in the URL, it's just blank.  Files are there

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error log, mybb is trying to find its files in `/var/www/mywebsite.com/php/`, but your `root` is set to `/var/www/mywebsite.com/`. So it looks like you didn't set it up properly. If you keep your `root` as is, you need to ensure that mybb's folders like `inc`, `admin`, etc. are subdirectories of `/var/www/mywebsite.com/`.